# How to rename output file(s) of Hive on EMR?

Tags: hadoop, amazon-s3, hive, emr, amazon-emr

The output of Hive on EMR is a file named 000000_0 (perhaps a different number if there is more than 1 reducer).

How do I get this file to be named differently?  I see two options:

1) Get Hive to write it differently

2) Rename the file(s) in S3 after it is written.  This is could be a problem: from what I've read S3 doesn't really have a "rename".  You have to copy it, and delete the original.  When dealing with a file that is 1TB in size, for example, this could cause performance problems or increase usage cost?

Answer (score 2):

The **[AWS Command Line Interface](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/)** (CLI) has a convenient `mv` command that you could add to a script:

```
aws s3 mv s3://my-bucket/000000_0 s3://my-bucket/data1
```

Or, you could do it programmatically via the [Amazon S3 `COPY` API call](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectCOPY.html).